# Man can give to woman

Tags: riddle

> Man can give it to a man,
>
> Man can also give it to woman,
>
> But woman can't give it to man,

**What is the thing?**

Comment: A jacket, because babes, man's not hot?

Comment: But can woman give it to woman?

Comment: It is not in the condition. So it maybe or may not be.

Answer (score 7):

Is it

> **His testicles**
>  A man has testicles, and can give them away. A woman does not. 
>  *(In the argument of fairness, I should say that I am confident this is not the answer. But it felt wrong for nobody to post it, as it is - technically - viable)*

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if I could've lived without this answer posted, and I also didnt' want to post it myself

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> **A father's advice**. Women can't give a father's advice, only man can give.

Comment: Pre 2000 I would say ok, in 2018 I better say no this is wrong.